# num_rows() returns 1 even when there are rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$this->db->select_sum('score_0')
    ->select_sum('score_1')
    ->select_sum('score_2')
          ..........
    ->select_sum('score_97')
    ->select_sum('score_98')
    ->select_sum('score_99');
    $this->db->where('score_game_id',$game_id);
    $this->db->order_by('score_id','asc');
    $query = $this->db->get($this->tbl_lotteryApp_scores_twodigit);     
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        }
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: There surely must be a way to use `RANGE` for all those.

Comment: why have you not added a loop? why such a long queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the best solution for this situation:

```
function sum_score($game_id){
    if($this->check_for_scores($game_id)==true)
    {
        $this->db->select_sum('score_0')
        ->select_sum('score_1')
        ->select_sum('score_2')
              ...........
        ->select_sum('score_98')
        ->select_sum('score_99');
        $this->db->where('score_game_id',$game_id);
        $this->db->order_by('score_id','asc');
        $query = $this->db->get($this->tbl_lotteryApp_scores_twodigit);     
        return  $query->result();
    }

}

function check_for_scores($game_id)
{
    $this->db->where('score_game_id',$game_id);
    $this->db->order_by('score_id','asc');
    $query = $this->db->get($this->tbl_lotteryApp_scores_twodigit);     
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){    
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

This worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

You will *always* get one row returned even if every value returned is zero because you have to return those zeros values as you are asking for them (run the sql from the command line and see). You need to get the results of your query and check their values to see what their actual values are.

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: You're going to have a really big if statement to check the values of all of those columns you selected